# iPad sending to iPhone via iMessage

Tags: messages

My iPad will not send an iMessage to 3 of my contacts.  I have been iMessaging with them for years, they are family and all have iPhones and haven't changed anything with their carriers, usage, etc.  All of a sudden I got the Not Delivered Message.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out what's the actual problem without more information or being at the scene. Some simple fixes you may try:

- Restart your iPad.
- Make sure you are not in airplane mode.
- Make sure you have interact connection. You can test by browsing a webpage.
- Go to 'Contact's and double check if their phone numbers (including country code) and/or apple id emails are correct.
- Test whether you can message others. If so, it might be your family's side's issue.